# Does youtube API or the allow music filters and repeat?

Tags: youtube-api

I would like to write a DJ's jukebox as a software which streams videos either from YouTube or from existing MP3s, and, I need to design the following:

1. playlists
2. repeat the same track
3. hopefully do some mixing as well
   based on treble, bass and other frequencies of music coming from
   different channels

...amongst others

Does YouTube allow this?  Can I code this kind of music mixer?  How?

Answer (score -2):

YouTube has no official API for this.

You could download videos from YouTube (e.g. with [yt-download](http://www.ytdownloader.com/)), and separate the audio (e.g. [`ffmpeg`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)`-i video.flv audio.mp3`); and use filters, like those provided by [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

Also, in many places downloading most music from YouTube is a violation of copyright law.  Distributing this application could get you in a lot of trouble, because you're encouraging people to break copyright law. <sub>(to my understanding)</sub>.